# What is proper procedure for entering iterative test flights into the aircraft's logs?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, faa

Let's say that I'm working on a problem which requires in-flight troubleshooting in an iterative process of multiple flights, for instance working on engine cooling baffles.  Does each iteration, no matter how minor, need to be entered in the a/c's logbook? That seems like a ridiculous way to spam the maintenance logbook with lots of meaningless lines.

What's the right thing to do?

- Log each change?
- Make the variations and then only log the final change?
- Log each change on an extra piece of paper, and then only copy the final change into the logbook?
- Something else?

Does the amount of idle time between test flights have an impact on the answer? How about whether it's a "major" or "minor" modification?

Comment: You mean airframe or engine log entries? In Canada we have Journey Logs, where all flights are recorded and are carried on the plane. I didn't think any flights had to be logged in the US.

Comment: @JohnK I mean the maintenance logs. The appropriate FAA logbook would be whichever component is affected. So if baffles, that would likely be only the engine log. But if it were tuning spade angles for optimum feel, that would be only the airframe log.

Comment: Last time I did was for flights needed to test repairs to an autopilot in a Piper single. Each flight is entered into the log with a note as to what the flight was about.